# What is the equivalent of the Confirmation composable on Jetpack Compose for mobile

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, wear-os, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I have been using the [confirmation composable](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/wear/compose/material/dialog/package-summary#Confirmation(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function1,androidx.wear.compose.foundation.lazy.ScalingLazyListState,kotlin.Long,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Function1)) in my Wear OS app for some time and I am now working on porting the app to mobile. What is the best equivalent for the confirmation composable on mobile compose as shown on [this page](https://developer.android.com/design/ui/wear/guides/components/dialogs)

I haven't found anything for mobile that matches the confirmation composable on Wear OS compose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use [toasts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts) in my mobile UI. To show a toast:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "The message you want to display", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```